# Counting features of point layer that are laying within polygon layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, count

I have a *'Layer 1'* that represents geographical areas. And another *'Layer 2'* contains some location-based information.

I want to count/aggregate the tweets per geographical using QGIS. For example, in the following screenshot. The count is 3 points(containing the one on the border if allowed), given that Layer 2 has no reference attribute that can be used to link with layer 1 (only the location of the feature).

Is there a way to do it using QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ["Count points in polygon"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#count-points-in-polygon) tool, which can be found under `Vector > Analysis Tools > Count points in polygon` as well as in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Answer (score 5):

Using QGIS expressions via field calculator:

1. select the polygonal layer;
2. start the field calculator;
3. create a new numeric field;
4. populates the field with the expression

```
aggregate (
  layer: = 'points',
  aggregate: = 'count',
  expression: = $id, 
  filter: = intersects ($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```